# Is this Registry "ShellNew" Key issue a known bug?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I ran into the following Registry issue.
When I export a "ShellNew" key as a back up before I change sth., the values which are displayed in hex format in the *.reg file (NOT n Regedit, where they are human readable), are "abbreviated". I.e.:

- Command >> c
- IconPath >> i
- MenuText >> m

Obviously, this is an issue, because restoring such a key will introduce the values "c", "i", and "m", which are useless.
Hence this situation boils down to permamently deleting values "Command", "IconPath", and "MenuText".
I could only restore them manually: either by correcting the *.reg file before running it, either directly in the Registry.
(IMHO the former is the best option, because this way you keep a correct BU of these values)

E.g. of such a key:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.contact\ShellNew]
I bothered to test with this key, as I don't use "contacts" in Windows, and because on my machine it only has these values.

But "ShellNew" keys also play a role when creating new Folders or ShortCuts with the Context Menu in Windows Explorer, so they are not without importance and impact.
Please note that the issue seems limited to Win7 (I'm on Win7 Ultimate, x64); I've been able to check it on Win10, and there everything seems normal.

Anyone out there having run into this behavkour as well? Is there another solution than intervening manually?
I've found zilch mention of it online, but as more users tweak around with shortcuts, it may have struck others in the past.

EDIT 1:

Came across another instance, indicating that the issue seems more generalized and not limited to "ShellNew" keys.
But the symptoms are the same: valuename cut off after its first letter when exported as a *.reg file.
Indeed, value "FriendlyTypeName" is abbreviated to "F" in at least a dozen sub-keys of
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes]
(e.g. batfile, Briefcase, chkfile, ...)

Moreover, @DavidPostill reports back that he cannot reproduce the issue on his Win7 Home Premium (x64). Thx for letting know.

EDIT 2:

It seems my question introduced a lot of confusion. I've only just come to realize that somehow the back-slash after "Classes" goes missing in the Preview and Final version of this queston, though it is present in the "edit zone". Is that a known issue with the Q&A editor on SuperUser? Is there a way to correct this anomaly?

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Comment: Provide some screenshots to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to provide the below screenshots requested by @Biswapriyo, I discovered that my issue seems to be a bug in the Registry tool I use! That's v8.04 of the [Registrar Registry Manager](http://www.resplendence.com/registrar). I've notified their Helpdesk.
Here's an example of the bug:

[image: Registrar bug - example]

And here's the Regedit equivalent:

[image: Same export via Regedit]

So, as Window's native Regedit does the export of these reg keys alright, I suppose this question can be closed?